# Overlay Section

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho mais ou menos a seguinte estrutura:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="tudo">
    <header>
          <nav></nav>
    </header>
    <div id="banner"></div>

    <section id="secao_1">
        <div>   
            conteudo normal 1
        </div>      

        <div>   
            conteudo normal 2
        </div>      
    </section>

    <section id="secao_over">
                    <div>
            conteudo overlay 1
                    <div>

                    <div
            conteudo overlay 2
                    <div>

                    <footer>
                        <div id="conteudo_rodape"></div>
                    </footer>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Preciso que conforme descer a barra de rolagem, vai chegar um momento em que a seção #secao_1 vai chegar no topo da tela, com isso, a seção #secao_over deverá começar a sobrepor o restante do conteúdo, e quando descer a barra de rolagem, o conteúdo overlay seguiria para o sua posição "normal".

Caso não tenha sido muito claro, só avisar que tento explicar melhor.

Comment: depois de `conteudo overlay 1 e 2` não deveria ser `</div>`?

Comment: Não entendi @Math, se estiver se referindo a semântica, rascunhei o html acima rapidamente, só para exemplificar a estrutura.

Comment: Como é só para exemplificar tudo bem, foi só algo que eu observei mas é irrelevante.

Comment: Faltam muitas `</div>` no seu HTML. Devia ser assim: http://jsfiddle.net/c2rPs/ e ainda não percebi o que quer fazer... dá para explicar melhor mais uma vez?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você está querendo fazer isso: 
**(usando jQuery)**

```js
$(window).on('scroll', scrolling);
function scrolling () {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop(); 
    var stop = $("#secao_1").offset().top;
    if(top < stop){
        // #secao_over sobrempoe
    }else{
        // #secao_over não sobrepõe
    }
}
```

Comment: Oi, Guilherme, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. O markdown aqui é um pouco diferente, confira http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Obrigado!! Agora entendi como faz.

Comment: Cara, a lógica está perfeita. Mas ainda não sei quais as propriedades CSS preciso setar para que ocorra a transição de overlay. Acho provável que precise setar tanto na section que irá sobrepor quanto que será sobreposta.

Comment: Você poderia explicar um pouco melhor então como seria essa sobreposição para eu tentar te ajudar com o css?